# Future cancel(boolean b) method not working when used in GUI application

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, future

I have the following code:

```
public class Cancelling {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ToBeCancelled tbc = new ToBeCancelled();
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(1);
    Future<?> future = pool.submit(tbc);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}

    future.cancel(true);
    if (future.isCancelled())
        System.out.println("The task has been cancelled");
}
}
```

With the `ToBeCancelled` class being:

```
public class ToBeCancelled implements Runnable {
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // should throw exception here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return; // should exit
    }

    System.out.println("I should never be able to print this");
}
}
```

The main thread should start, wait for 3 seconds, and then cancel the `ToBeCancelled` task by using `future.cancel(true)`. It then should print `The task has been cancelled`, while the task never gets to print its message.
At least, this is what happens when I start it from console.

As I start it from a GUI application with a TextArea where the output is redirected to, that's not the case. The main method does print `The task has been cancelled`, but the task also prints `I should never be able to print this`.

This is driving me insane. From what I understand the task should receive its `cancel` command while on the `Thread.sleep(5000)` method, which would fire an exception that is consequently caught and makes the thread return. But it doesn't happen and yet the main thinks it has been cancelled. It's like the `cancel` method is completely ignored by the task.

I've tried everything I could think of, checking on the returned value of `cancel`, making the task wait longer, using `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`, but nothing works.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple, but I just can't find what it is. Any idea?

In case anyone thinks it might be something on the GUI application, this is the method that starts the program:

```
public static void StartProgram(String name) {
    try {
        Method m = Class.forName(name).getDeclaredMethod("main",String[].class);
        Object[] args = new Object[1];
        String s[] = new String[2];
        s[0] = tf1.getText();
        s[1] = tf2.getText();
        args[0] = s;
        t = new Thread(new ProgramStarter(args, m));
        t.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

With `ProgramStarter` being:

```
public class ProgramStarter implements Runnable {
private Object[] args;
private Method m;

public ProgramStarter(Object args[], Method m) {
    this.args = args;
    this.m = m;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        m.invoke(null, args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that enough time has passed and the thread comes out of sleep before the interrupt that causes the exception? Try increasing the sleep time.

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't change anything. I'm also sure that's not it because when the main program prints "The Task has been interrupted" it means it already invoked the cancel method, and 2 seconds after that the task says "I should never be able to print this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your verification is wrong. You think that your code works when running from the console but in fact, it fails in all cases. When running from the console your main thread ends after the attempt to cancel the future and the JVM will terminate as there are only daemon threads left in the JVM. Due to the JVM termination you don’t notice that the cancellation did not work.

When adding a `sleep` at the end of your `main` method to delay the JVM termination you will notice that `"I should never be able to print this"` is printed when running from the console as well. So the only difference between GUI and console version is that the running Event Dispatch Thread prevents the JVM from terminating so you see that it doesn’t work.

---

The bottom line is: *don’t use* `ForkJoinPool` *unless you have a reason for this*.

Since you just want `submit` to a simple single-background-thread executor, you can create the executor using `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`. This has less unexpected behavior: it’s thread is non-daemon by default and it’s `Future` will `cancel` with interruption as expected.

Comment: Yep, that was it. Adding sleep made it print that in console as well, and Executors solved my problem. Thanks.